# React Maximum state update error trying to define an array of objects on userEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a product insert component, and every time I try to add an array of objects with useState inside d useEffect I get the state update limit error. The other common string fields update the state without error, arriving at the object list update get the error. Has anyone please ever been through this?

Code: https://gist.github.com/nathancn/5c1b549c3f541702a69e46b3e0547d60
Line error: 49

react maximum update depth exceeded

Comment: Please include a [mcve] inside the question description.

Answer (score 2):

There is a code for the parent component missing but I would guess, that defineCurrentDataByCodigo is called within the effect, which updates the parent, which updates the props, which calls useEffect and causes the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem! The problem is, *react doesn't let us use large sequences from different setState*s.

My code synchronously updated the data objects returned from my "API". The error was generated because when setting the date of the sub products had already used the "useState" many times I changed to update only one object I named "dataCurrentProduct" and in JSX return changed the .map to use "dataCurrentProduct". subProducts "and so on. Thanks for the quick answers, I figured I could use several "useState" as long as it was not in infinite loop and crashing the process, but I saw that even without loop we have limit on "useState"